# want to send some packets to pox controller connected with mininet

Tags: python, sdn, pox

I am new in pox controller want to write a code where switch will send some packet to controller and controller will send hello packet to the switch

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, to improve your odds to get an useful answer, I suggest you to [improve your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (what did you try, etc.).

Comment: actually i have connected pox with mininet(having two host one switch) now i want to send some packet from switch to pox and after that pox will send hello to switch

Comment: In the terminal running mininet issue a pingall to send packets.

Comment: yes thats correct but pingall send ICMP packet but i want to send TCP/UDP packet

Answer (score 0):

If you want TCP packets with mininet you can use Python to setup a simple HTTP server and perform a wget like opening the page hosted there

Assuming you start mininet with

```
sudo mn --controller remote
```

Then you have 2 hosts h1, h2. Use h1 to run a simple http server and h2 to read the site from that server

```
mininet> h1 python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 &
mininet> h2 wget -O - h1
```